# React I receive Infinite Loop on Error Boundry / Handling errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, error-handling, react-hooks

I try to have an Error Boundry for async actions, but then I get an infinite loop. Do you have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? I tried to add my own hook to catch the errors - and it works but it probably provides an infinite loops unfortunatelly

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog'
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions'
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent'
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText'
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'

export class ErrorHandler extends Component {
  state = { error: false }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { error }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    this.setState({ error: true })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ error: false })
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.error ? (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.error}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby='alert-dialog-title'
          aria-describedby='alert-dialog-description'
        >
          <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>{'Error occured'}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
              Error description
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              onClick={this.handleClose}
              autofocus
            >
              OK
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    ) : (
      this.props.children
    )
  }
}
```

ErrorHandling:

```
<ErrorHandler>
  <App />
</ErrorHandler>
```

Custom Hook to catch async errors:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'

const useAsyncError = () => {
  const [_, setError] = useState()
  return useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setError(() => {
        throw e
      })
    },
    [setError]
  )
}

export default useAsyncError
```

Using it:

```
function Dashboard() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const throwError = useAsyncError()

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      reportService
        .getWelcomeReport(request)
        .then(
          (response) => setData(response.data)
        )
        .catch((e) => {
          throwError(new Error('Asynchronous error'))
        })
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>TEST</div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```